# Find the words stored for the given set of characters

Tags: string, algorithm

I was asked this question in one of the interview. I was given characters (let's say char array strAlphabets:) 't' 'u' 'v' 'm' 'n' 'o' and 'p'  and I have to read out all the possible words with one,two or all the characters of it. For this I was also asked store some possible words with one,two...or all the characters first in whatever the structure I want.

E.g. first I should store some words such as moon, top, pot, no, vot etc...
Then if user gives 't' 'p' and  'o' as input  then I should output "top" and "pot" from the words which I already stored.

any idea how to implement this ?

Comment: To make sure I fully understand your question: you have the word list in advance, then are given the set of characters.  You then want to find all words in the list that use at least one of the given characters.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Like this? (Please, don't comment on any syntactical errors, treat it as pseudocode)

```
bool IsAWord(string word, char[] alphabet)
{
 foreach(char c in word)
   if (alphabet.indexof(c)==-1)
     return false;

 return true;
}

void SolveThePuzzle (string[] words, char[] alphabet)
{
  foreach (string word in words)
    if (IsAWord(word,alphabet))
      Console.Writeln(word+' is a word');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must a dictionary to such of algorithms. After you generate all possible permutations (or a part of that) you must to use this dictionary.

Comment: No. These are no permutations, not even variations of any length as each character can appear multiple times. Constructing 'words' from chars is a very simple grammar and creates an infinite number of words. So creating all words and then check whether the created words match the list wont help